# Any other prime numbers that satisfy this condition?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

If $a=2$ and $b=3$, then $a^2-1$ is an integer multiple of $b$. Is there any other pair of primes $a$ and $b$ that satisfy this relationship? I don't think so, but can't figure out why not.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of them, infinite of them to be exact. Set $a= \text{any prime} =p$ and $b$ to any prime divisor of $p^2-1$.

Comment: True, thanks! What if $a<b$?