# Any other prime numbers that satisfy this condition #2

Tags: number-theory

Here,

[Any other prime numbers that satisfy this condition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598751/any-other-prime-numbers-that-satisfy-this-condition)

I asked if $a=2$ and $b=3$, then $a^2-1$ is an integer multiple of $b$. Is there any other pair of primes $a$ and $b$ that satisfy this relationship? The answer is yes, there are infinite pairs: set $a= \text{any prime} =p$ and $b$ to any prime divisor of $p^2-1$. If we add the condition that $a<b$, are there any other pairs?

More Clearly,

> Are there primes $a,b$ where $a<b$ such that $a^2 -1$ is an integer multiple of $b$, aside from $a=2,b=3$?

Answer (score 4):

No. $a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1)$ certainly has no prime divisors $>a+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hagen von Eitzen gave a very good succinct explanation, but I had some doubts and tried to attack it differently.

I noted that $a^2-1$ is necessarily even, so if $kb=a^2-1$, we must have $2pb=a^2-1$, where $p,k \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried to show this implies $b\leq a$, but didn't get very far.

Still having doubts, I wrote a Python script to computationally check the proposition. I know this isn't a proof at all, I'm just sharing this hoping that it might be somehow helpful.

The `primes.txt` file is just a copy-paste of [this list of the first 1000 primes](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt), though you could of course do it with a larger list of primes if you wanted to. The code for my script is available [here](http://pastebin.com/rSXX493c).